# How to implement enable/disable behavior like ApplicationCommands.Cut on user control

Tags: wpf, focus, controls, toolbar, behavior

I've created a user control that is a Toolbar with a couple buttons on it.  The toolbar contains some general functions like copy, paste, undo, redo, etc.  These buttons use the built in commands like so.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Foundation.FundRaising.DataRequest.Windows.Controls.TextEditorToolBar"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="34" d:DesignWidth="550">
<Grid>
    <telerik:RadToolBar>
        <telerik:RadToolBar.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
            </Style>
        </telerik:RadToolBar.Resources>
        <telerik:RadButton Command="Cut">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="/Foundation.FundRaising.DataRequest.Windows;component/Resources/cut20.png" ToolTip="Cut"/>
                <Label Content="Cut"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </telerik:RadButton>
        <telerik:RadButton Command="Copy">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="/Foundation.FundRaising.DataRequest.Windows;component/Resources/copy20.png" ToolTip="Copy"/>
                <Label Content="Copy"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </telerik:RadButton>
        <telerik:RadButton Command="Paste">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="/Foundation.FundRaising.DataRequest.Windows;component/Resources/paste20.png" ToolTip="Paste"/>
                <Label Content="Paste"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </telerik:RadButton>
        <telerik:RadButton Command="Delete">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="/Foundation.FundRaising.DataRequest.Windows;component/Resources/delete24.png" ToolTip="Delete"/>
                <Label Content="Delete"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </telerik:RadButton>

        <telerik:RadToolBarSeparator/>

        <telerik:RadButton Command="Undo">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="/Foundation.FundRaising.DataRequest.Windows;component/Resources/undo20.png" ToolTip="Undo"/>
                <Label Content="Undo"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </telerik:RadButton>
        <telerik:RadButton Command="Redo">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="/Foundation.FundRaising.DataRequest.Windows;component/Resources/redo20.png" ToolTip="Redo"/>
                <Label Content="Redo"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </telerik:RadButton>
        <telerik:RadButton x:Name="radButtonSpellCheck" Click="RadButtonSpellCheckClick">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="/Foundation.FundRaising.DataRequest.Windows;component/Resources/spell_check24.png" ToolTip="Spell Check"/>
                <Label Content="Spell Check"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </telerik:RadButton>            
    </telerik:RadToolBar>
</Grid>
```

I've added a "Spell Check" button that uses the Telerik RadSpellChecker control, like so.

```
    private void RadButtonSpellCheckClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            IInputElement control = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
            RadSpellChecker.Check((Control)control, SpellCheckingMode.AllAtOnce);
        }
        catch (NotImplementedException)
        {
            RadWindow.Alert("You have selected a control that does not support the spell check feature.");
        }
    }
```

All of this works fine, but what I would like to do is have the "Spell Check" button enable/disable when a control is focused like the built in commands do, without having to catch the exception and displaying the alert to the user.  Bascially, making the determination whether or not the focused control can accept the "functionality".

Comment: Bind your button's Visibility to IsKeyboardFocused Property of the control and create converter to convert bool to Visibility

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  When you say "property of the control and...", are you referring to the control that has focus?  If so, how would go about getting the path to that control?  IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=????, Path=IsKeyboardFocused}"

Comment: `<telerik:RadButton x:Name="radButtonSpellCheck" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=yourControlName, Path=IsKeyboardFocused, Mode=OneWay}"` no need to Converter

Comment: I set the Path equal to the x:Name of my user control, but the button doesn't become "enabled".  Also, I didn't see any binding errors.

Comment: try IsKeyboardFocusWithin and don't forget the Mode to OneWay

Comment: That doesn't work either.  Also, since the "elementname" is pointing to the my usercontrol, won't it always be "false"?  Shouldn't the "elementName" be the control that has the current focus?